# Angulardart + Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, angular-dart

I just tried angulardart, I want to use mongodb as a database, I use package: mongo_dart, this is my code

[**main.dart**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktAKa.png)

can be seen, I want to retrieve data from the Mongo database "contact-db" collection "contact-collection" then display it on the console, but I get this error

[**error in console chrome**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIeYS.png)

"dart_sdk.js:4835 Uncaught core.UnsupportedError.new {Symbol(UnsupportedError.message): "Socket constructor", Symbol(_error): Error
    at Object.dart.throw (http://localhost:8080/packages/$sdk/dev_compiler/amd/dart_sdk.js:483…"

what I want to ask is:

1. Is this error from a package, if there is a solution for this error?
2. does this error come from my code, if so please give me a solution?
3. Is there another way to use it so that I can use angulardart with mongodb as a database?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot use `dart:io` or connect to databases from a web browser.

Comment: what should i do to find out the angulardart connected with mongodb ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, mongodb can only be accessed from a server-side application. Saying that, you would need to create 2 applications, one for client-side written using `angular-dart` and another one for the server-side using `shelf` maybe.

Right now the only databases that allows connecting directly from the client-side are `firebase` and `firestore`.

Comment: does 'shelf' support for Mongodb ?